# refreshing a page with different content after form submission

Tags: php

I want to have a php contact form, that when submitted (if no errors), will refresh the same page, and remove the contact form, and replace it with some text e.g. "thank you for contacting us".
Is there a best way to do this?

Comment: make a flag (0 or 1) for whether the submit was successful or not. when you load the page check the flag and display what you need to based on its value

Answer (score 2):

You could always do something like this:

```
<?php
    $posted = false;
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        /* Process $_POST */

        /* Do your things */

        /* Set a variable hinting if a post has been done */ 
        $posted = true;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php if( $posted ): ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input name="foo" />
            <input name="bar" />
            <input name="car" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h1>Thank you for contacting us!</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An interesting addition to this excellent answer, is that by using hidden form fields, you can create multi-page forms that all run in one script. By using a `switch` or similar on the value of a consistent hidden field (i.e. 'pg'), you can choose to display the next part of the form.

Comment: Great answers, one question. you have if($posted):, and else:, I have never come across the colons : before for if and else statements, can these be used in lieu of curly brackets {}?

Comment: @user1925900: Yup. I usually use the `:`'s in situations as the one above, and curly brackets when... well, pretty much anytime else. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.

```
<?php

$showform=true;  //dispaying the form for the first time

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

       //check for errors
       if($errors){
          $msg="errors";
          $showform=true;  // if found errors, setting error msg and displaying the form
       }else{
          //process the form
          $showform=false;  //if no errors, setting success msg and hiding the form
          $msg="SUccess";
       }
}

if(isset($msg)){
         //display the success/error msg
         echo $msg;
}
if($showform==true){

   //your form code
   <form method="post">
        <input name="foo" />
        <input name="bar" />
        <input name="car" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
}


?>
```